# Android - Why do some of the method names in Play services get garbled?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am using Google Sign in my project. There was a method named `zzmI()` of class `GoogleSignInAccount` in the `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0`.

When I updated Play Services to version 10.0.1, i.e. `com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1`, I am getting an `error: cannot find symbol method zzmI()`, although there are some other methods starting with `zz`.

I don't know, whether the support for this method has been removed, or the name of the methods changed. My guess is that only name of the method differs.

How can I get the proper name of the method, so that it does not differ version by version ?

Answer (score 0):

Any garbled name, is an obsfucated non-public method or variable, which you should not be accessing in the first place. If you are not accessing them, then it's probably a build issue, and just doing a clean should solve the issue.